# Disallow whitespaces in regex

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

I have this code:

```
    private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+"); // Regex that matches disallowed text
        return !regex.IsMatch(text);
    }

    private void TextboxClientID_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);
    }
```

This allows whitespaces in the textbox, how to prevent from inserting whitespaces too?

Comment: Can you provide an example string that is considered valid and invalid?

Comment: I just have a textbox in the MainWindow and using the code above I can insert only digits and whitespaces to it. I want it to disallow the user from inserting whitespaces too.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Baffles me that it has 4 upvotes...

Answer (score 4):

In regex, the `\s` modifier translates to `[\r\n\t\f ]`, which means no `newline` characters, no `tab` characters, no `form feed` characters (used by printers to start a new page), and no `spaces`.

So you can use the regex `[^\\s]` (you have to use `\\` in order to make a single `\`, which will then translate to `\s` finally. If you just use `\s`, it will translate to s character literal.

The beginning and ending `^` and `$` characters match the beginning and end of the string respectively.

So, you could use the regex `^[^0-9\\s]+$`. Here is a breakdown of what it does:

- The first `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- Next, we have the group inclosed in `[]`, which will match any single character in that group
- Inside of the `[]`, we have `^0-9\\s`:

  - The `^` character makes sure that no single character inside of the `[]` will be matched (switches it from any single character to no single character), none of the following should be true
  - The `0-9` part matches any number between 0 and 9
  - The `\\s` part creates literally `\s`. `\s` matches any whitespace character
- The `+` matches the group inclosed in `[]` between 1 and infinite times
- The final `$` matches the end of the string

Your code could be:

```
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text){
    Regex regex = new Regex("^[^0-9\\s]+$");
    return !regex.IsMatch(text);
}
```

Here's a regex101 test: https://regex101.com/r/aS9xT0

Comment: I've already tryied it. It does not work, I still can insert whitespaces to the textbox...

Comment: @user2519090 Check my updated answer, it should work better now

Comment: @user2519090: take care to notice that when there are no anchors (^, $) in your `pattern`, then `regex.IsMatch` returns `true` when the pattern matches **anything and anywhere** in the `text`. To ensure that the whole `text` matches the pattern, you **must use both anchors**.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but none of your suggestions works. I tried to use     Regex regex = new Regex("\\S");    But this allows me to insert nothing but whitespaces. But if I use    Regex regex = new Regex("^\\S");    It does not change anything, and still only whitespaces can be inserted to the textbox.

Comment: This is a long code. I think I pasted the relevant part here. If you need another part of it, just tell me what you need...

Comment: @user2519090 I just read your updated comment. If you would like to disallow all whitespaces, and only whitespaces, you have to use `Regex regex = new Regex("^[^\\s]+$);` (remember, everything in the regex is CaSE-SEnsiTiVE, so `\\s` is not the same as `\\S`. In your question you denied numbers, and asked what to add to make it disallow whitespaces, also, and the regex in the answer, `^[^0-9\\s]+$` should work for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[^0-9 ]+$
```

Try this.This will not allow whitespaces at all.

Answer (score 2):

*NOT a regex answer, I had the same issue with the space char's

I fixed this by adding `PreviewKeyDown` on the `TextBox` and setting `e.Handled` to `true` if spacebar has been pressed, just like this:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@"^[^\d\s]+$"
```

\d ... Match a digit (0-9).
\s ... Match a whitespace character.

---

```
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[^\d\s]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you bother with regex ? Simply use:

```
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
{
    return text.All(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question.. But to disallow whitespaces use the "Any non-whitespace character" `\S` coupled with a multiplier `+`. It will match basically anything, even '∆', but no whitespaces (\n, \r, \t, \f, \v)

```
\S+
```

But a number input without whitespace can simply be, as @vks mentioned;

```
^[0-9]+$
```